# How to print the fields data to a specific area of a A4 paper?

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a ms access query based form which needs to print out (overlay) on a pre-printed form located inside the printer. The pre-printed form in the printer has 10 blank fields in different area of the page. I need to print those query based form data to those 10 blank fields to the accurate positions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a ruler and get the top-left coordinates of the 10 areas
   relative to the top-left margin of the preprinted form.
2. Design your report, setting top and left margin to match the form,
   and then assign the coordinates from above to the 10 fields.

Comment: Thank you Gustav. I would give it a try.